# Azure Insights data for web app service : Why response time shown for Ajax call and controller method can have large difference

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have following controller class and a PUT method in an azure app service (.NET C#)

```
MyController {

     [MyApiRoute("anapi")]
    // PUT: anapi/items
    [HttpPut("items")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<AnObject>> ManageLineItems()
    {
        //some code here....
    }

}
```

I am trying to measure performance of making a call to this REST URL using azure insights. It shows  First line with AJAX call as 7.7 sec and second line with controller method as 3.9 seconds as shown in diagram. My understanding is that first line in azure insights would correspond to call to this URL and second line corresponds to the time the method in controller took to execute. If that is correct, were typically on azure app service would 7.7 sec - 3.9 sec would be spent? This doesn't appear to be time spent by my code.
If my understanding about these two lines in azure insights is incorrect, can any experts here explain me what this means? Also, were could 2.8 seconds which is difference between total execution for route and method would have been spent?

Please let me know if i need to provide more details about the problem.

[image]

Comment: Could you check this [document](https://codingcanvas.com/end-to-end-correlation-using-azure-application-insights-for-asp-net-mvc-apps/) and let me know if it clears your doubt.

Comment: Yes, i am able to understand it better based  on this document. However one part that i am still unable to understand is - in above picture i posted, both calls are in same service. So unable to understand why it calls one as outgoing service and another as incoming service. I think i need to understand the problem better and phrase and explain my question better. I will try to do so next week. Thank you for checking this.

Comment: Yeah sure, let me know once you have edited the question. Will try to help you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Application Insights is a full-scale application performance monitoring tool which does much more than only logging. It is **Application Performance Management (APM) service for collecting and monitoring the application log data**

In the above picture in your question, the first line represents the outgoing dependency form your web service and the following line represents the incoming request. **And the duration column you see is the cumulative request duration at each level**.

> If Service A calls service B then from point of view of Service A , call to Service B is an ‘**Outgoing dependency’** and when this request is received at Service B then from its point of view the call is an ‘**Incoming request’** from service A. That's the reason App insights captures both of them .

This is called end to end correlation, which works by default when you enable application insight.

I would suggest to read this [End to end correlation using Azure application insights for `asp.net` mvc apps](https://codingcanvas.com/end-to-end-correlation-using-azure-application-insights-for-asp-net-mvc-apps/) document to understand the entire to understand hierarchical view of the request flow telling which service or API calls happened along with where and at what point exception occurred along with all the logs / traces that happened during that request.